# Is a subspace of a vectorspace "closed"

Tags: vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

Suppose we have some vector space $V$ with subspace $U$. Is it true that if $v$ is a vector in $V$, and if $v+U$ is always in $U$, then $v$ is actually in $U$ itself?

The converse is obviously true, but I don't really know where to start with this.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the quantifiers in this question. Are you asking whether $(\forall v \in V) \: [((\forall u \in U) u+v \in U) \Rightarrow v \in U]$? The answer to that question is yes, because if $u+v \in U$ then $(u+v)+(-u)$ is a representation of $v$ as a linear combination of elements of $U$.

Comment: I believe you mean "and if $v+u$ is always in $U$ where $u\in U$".

Answer (score 4):

The null vector is in $U$, and by hypothesis $v+0$ is in $U$, hence $v$ is in $U$.

Comment: I think this is not the intended meaning of the quantifiers in the OP. See my comment.

Comment: @Ian It may be simply a misuse of the word "always", perhaps meaning $\forall u\in U$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me type what I think you're asking.

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space, $U$ a subspace of $V$, and $v \in V$.  If $$v + U = \{v + u : u \in U\}$$ is contained in $U$, then in fact $v \in U$.

Proof: Since $0 \in U$, we have $v + 0 \in  v + U \subseteq U$, so there exists a $u \in U$ such that $v + 0 = u \in U$.  But then $v = u \in U$.  Q.E.D.

More generally we have a notion of cosets in a group.  If $G$ is a group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $g \in G$, then we can talk about the set $gH = \{ gh: h \in H\}$.  It is a fact that different cosets $g_1H, g_2H$ are either *disjoint* (their intersection is the empty set) or else they are equal.